# Laravel stop populating updated_at but still insert created_at

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following model

```
class PasswordResets extends Model
{

 protected $table = 'password_resets';
  protected $fillable = [
  'token', 'email'
 ];

  public function setUpdatedAt($value){
       ;
   }//tried this but fails to work
}
```

I have tried using the function `setUpdatedAt` but still fails

The way I am using this model is

```
   $passwordreset = PasswordResets::where('email', $user->email)->first();
  if(!$passwordreset){
     //insert user to password reset
      $passwordreset = new PasswordResets();
      $passwordreset->email = $user->email;
  }
  $passwordreset->token = sha1(time());
  if($passwordreset->save()){
     //send emails to user  

  }
```

Basically am trying to find if a user exist in a password reset table other wise add a new one then send email.

Every time I try, I am getting an error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at'

Which is true since my table only contains the column `created_at`.

How do I stop the `updated_at` from being filled up?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel automatically tries to set the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields every time you create or edit a model.  If you don't want to use that functionality, add this to your model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

You will then have to set your `created_at` column manually.

To automate the `created_at` column, just use a default in your migration:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->default('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
```

Comment: is it possible to retain only the created_at functionality not have to set it manually.